# need calculated column for every empId

Tags: sql, sql-server

## Table 1 (Main Table with some more other fields)

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Emp Id  Pgm_Start Date End Date       Total_No_of_Days
----------------------------------------------------------
 - ID001    11/04/2103    11/10/2013       7
 - ID001    10/05/2013    10/08/2013       4
 - ID002    10/09/2013    10/15/2013       7
 - ID002    09/02/2013    09/06/2013       5
```

**My below Query  Gives the following :**

```
SELECT EmpID,COUNT(ProgramID) AS Total_Programs, 
SUM(CAST(Total_No_Of_Days AS INT)) AS Total_Program_Days from table1  
GROUP BY empid ORDER BY Total_Programs desc,Total_Program_Days desc  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Emp Id  Total_Program   Total_Program_Days   Days_since_last_Program
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 - ID001     2            11                     ---need this value---
 - ID002     2            12                     ---need this value----
```

I want to calculate the last field(Days_since_last_Program) based on the table1 for each and every employee..

so I workout...

This query is giving the last Program End_date for ‘ID001’

```
 SELECT * from table1 where  End_Date= (select
 MAX(Convert(Date,End_Date))  from table1 where EmpId=’ID001’) and
 EmpID=ID001
```

---

so , finally getting the value But I’m getting this for single user:

```
 SELECT ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
(SELECT End_date from table1 where  
 End_Date = (select    MAX(Convert(Date,End_Date))  
 FROM table1 where EmpId=ID001) and
 EmpID=ID001))) as "Days_since_last_Program"
```

I want this calculated value for all employees  as column  "Days since last Program"  but cant figure out how,please help me to figure out..
Thank You in advance..

Comment: Please see all the details..I need the last column(Days since last Program) for all employees

Comment: How do you compute days since last program? It's not very clear in your post.

Comment: look!  for ID001   the last Program End_date is 11/10/2013  "mm/dd/yy" format . so  Days since last Program= difference between End_date and Current_date

Comment: Seeing those `CONVERT`s makes me worry - why is `EndDate` not being stored as `date` already?

Answer (score 0):

is it not just as simple as...

```
SELECT 
    EmpID,
    COUNT(ProgramID) AS Total_Programs, 
    SUM(CAST(Total_No_Of_Days AS INT)) AS Total_Program_Days,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(CONVERT(DATE,End_Date)), GETDATE()) AS Days_Since_Last_Program
FROM table1
GROUP BY empid 
ORDER BY Total_Programs DESC,Total_Program_Days DESC
```

Comment: You r life saver James,after some tweaking  I got the answer  thanks

Answer (score 0):

just little modification in your query posted ..

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE end_date = (SELECT MAX(convert(DATE, t2.end_date)) 
                     FROM table1 t2 
                    WHERE t2.empid = t1.empid)
```

just you need to get conform that for one user end_date is not getting repeating.
otherwise you may get multiple rows for same users.

Comment: definitely u r right ..in the above query I was getting two users for the same end_date

Answer (score 0):

This will work using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(
        SELECT MAX(Convert(Date,t2.End_Date))  
        from table1 t2
        where t2.EmpId=t1.EmpId
    ))) AS [Days_since_last_Program]

FROM table1 t1;
```